# Chaining switchMap

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to understand what happens when two (or more) `switchMap`s are chained.

I'm using this sample code:

```
.switchMap(r => someCondition(r) ? Observable.throw(r._body) : Observable.of(r.json()))
.switchMap(r => r.error ? Observable.throw(new Error(r.error)) : Observable.of(r))
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

What will happen here? If `someCondition(r)` is true, a `throw` will happen, and from there, I believe the `catch` will be executed. If `someCondition(r)` is false, then the second `switchMap` will get in, but what would it receive as parameter? The `json()` output of `r`? Or just `r`?

Or maybe I'm completely wrong, in which case can I get an explanation of what exactly is happening in there?

Comment: What happened when you actually ran it?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I can't actually run the code since I can't reproduce all the possible conditions of `r`, so I'm trying to understand how it will behave.

Comment: Sure, but it's definitely possible to mock up a much simpler case (where e.g. `someCondition` is just replaced with `true` or `false`).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I can replace `someConditon` with true/false, but that's the most I can go without further understanding how actually `switchMap` handles chaining.

Comment: `switchMap(r => some_made_up_logic).subscribe(x => console.log(x))` would allow you to observe (pun intended) the behaviour of `switchMap` in various scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen here? If someCondition(r) is true, a throw will happen, and from there, I believe the catch will be executed.

Yes.

> If someCondition(r) is false, then the second switchMap will get in, but what would it receive as parameter? The json() output of r? Or just r?

The first `switchMap` would return `Observable.of(r.json())` that would be then flattened, so `r` in the second `switchMap` will be `r.json()`